# Is there any way to draw a shape in JavaFX Canvas with "inside" stroke type using GraphicsContext?

Tags: java, kotlin, javafx, canvas

I have a Canvas in JavaFX, and I would like to draw, say, a Circle, or Polygon, with stroke inside.
This is what I would usually do:

```
class MyClass {
    fun draw(ctx: GraphicsContext, points: List<Point>) {
        ctx.beginPath()
        points.forEach {
            ctx.lineTo(it.x, it.y)
        }
        ctx.closePath()
        ctx.fill()
        ctx.stroke()
    }
}
```

But the problem is, this method will draw the shape with the stroke on path, like on the left on this picture:
[image]
I need it to draw the stroke inside the path.

I know that this is possible in JavaFX Shapes with their `javafx.scene.shape.StrokeType` patameter, but I would like to avoid using them as they need to be manually added to the Node as children (and manually removed if I need to change something).

Also, I know that I can use `ctx.clip()` to imitate the desired effect. But this method, if used frequently (which is my case), causes unacceptable lags to the application.

I searched everywhere to find a Canvas analog of StrokeType parameter, but haven't found anything.

Comment: *"I searched everywhere to find a Canvas analog of StrokeType parameter, but haven't found anything."* -> As of JavaFX 19, I don't think that there is a Canvas analog of the StrokeType parameter.  The only suggestion I have is to calculate a different path, such that the line will appear where you want it to.  That is simple enough in basic cases, but likely difficult in a general sense.